# Can an electron's spin reverse if we lived in a nonorientable universe?

Tags: quantum-spin

If the universe was nonorientable; to the best of my understanding, that would imply that there exists some loop through space that would flip right handed coordinates into left handed coordinates. In this case, does it mean that even the spins of elementary particles could be reversed; or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, perhaps this?: Moving with velocity **v** - non parallel to an external magnetic field **B**- electrons due to their spin get deflected. The direction of this deflection is described by the Lorentz force and the right hand rule or the vector product from **B** and **v**.  This solution is not the only one. The electron could theoretical move in the opposite direction like a positron ( the antiparticle of the electron).  Is our question about which conditions of our world have to be reverse to let deflect the electron in the other direction?